# How do I feed Unity Web Player extern data?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I am new to using Unity3D, and I am supposed to use it on a web application (which is build with Ruby on Rails).

My problem is that I need to feed it data from my database but I don`t know how to give it extern data.

I`d appreciate any kind of help. :)

Comment: Unity Web Player is no longer supported by Unity and ideally should not be used. [Read More Here](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/10/08/unity-web-player-roadmap/)

Comment: Also Unity Web Player will not work at all in Chrome browsers (details in the link in the comment above).

Comment: Web Browsers are still supported but no through web-player. WebGL replaced web player

Answer (score 1):

You can use WWW to make a request on the server and receive data.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html (see the 2nd example)

Note that Unity Webplayer is no longer updated and its already removed from Unity 5.4 ( http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/10/08/unity-web-player-roadmap/ )